# C# DragDrop from toolStrip

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, toolstrip

I'm looking for a way to determine which item in a toolStrip that was dragged after a DragDrop event has occured, all I want to do is make a switch case with different cases for each item in the toolstrip but I cant seem to find a way of comparing them.

**UPDATE: SHORT CODESAMPLE**

```
private void toolStrip1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    //Here I want something like a DoDragDrop() and send the specific item from the
    //toolstrip..
}

private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //And here some way to determine which of the items was dragged 
    //(I'm not completely sure if I need a mouseUp event though..)
}
```

Hopefully a bit easier to get what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: You can't do switch on reference types such as UI controls. You will have to do if/else if/else. If you provide some code from your handler and also where your UI is defined (.designer file) we could be of more help.

Comment: Didn't think code sample was nessecary since all it is is a toolstrip with 2 buttons, and an empty panel. What I want is to raise a dragdrop event when I drag something from the toolstrip into the panel and then determine which of the items in the toolstrip was draged, for now its just 2 buttons but I can only assume there is a way to compare the text of the buttons in the strip, and I want something like a switch case for each button (or just a coupple of if's if thats what it takes).

Comment: @Jacco: A code sample would keep me from having to recreate your situation in a project, which I am not keen to do. Please create an OnDrop handler in your Panel and write some code, even if it's crap, to signal your intent. Please.

Comment: updated the question, hopefully its easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The events in your example don't look like the correct events to use.

Here is a working example from a ToolStrip that has 2 ToolStripButtons on it:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  toolStripButton1.MouseDown += toolStripButton_MouseDown;
  toolStripButton2.MouseDown += toolStripButton_MouseDown;

  panel1.DragEnter += panel1_DragEnter;
  panel1.DragDrop += panel1_DragDrop;
}

void toolStripButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  this.DoDragDrop(sender, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
  e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
  ToolStripButton button = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ToolStripButton))
                           as ToolStripButton;
  if (button != null) {
    if (button.Equals(toolStripButton1)) {
      MessageBox.Show("Dragged and dropped Button 1");
    } else if (button.Equals(toolStripButton2)) {
      MessageBox.Show("Dragged and dropped Button 2");
    }
  }
}
```